# Multiple drop menus with one PHP script

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

Website has several pages with forms. Many of which have drop menus. I would like to write one PHP script that will populate multiple drop menus. I'm including the code I have so far, but I don't think I'm on the right track here.

order.php

```
<?php 
    include 'functionsFile.php'; 
?>

<form method="post" action="order.php">
    <select name="order_status" id="order_status">
        <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <option><?=$row["order_status"]?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
    <!-- 3 More Drop Menus -->
</form>
<?php
    $table = array('order_status', 'customer', 'warehouse_id', 'order_description');
    fillForm($conn, $table);
?>
```

functionsFile.php

```
<?php
    require 'databaseConnection.php';

 function fillForm($conn, $table)
 {
    foreach ($table as $menu)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM $table';
        $smt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $smt->execute();
        $data = $smt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

**Additional Information**

1. I am wondering if I will have to add a parameter to the fillForm() function so it knows the field names as well. Alternatively, I am querying tables that have only one pertinent data field, so is it bad practice to name the (one important) data field the same as the table?
2. I'm already not sure how to control the output of what is going on in this code. If I should add a second array to the parameters, I'll be totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few errors in your code, so hopefully these fixes will help you out. First of all, your `functionsFile.php` file is called after you try to use the data that it generates. This needs to happen before you try to use the `$data` variable. Secondly, your `fillForm()` function doesn't return a value. Instead, you are creating a scoped variable that will not be accessible from outside of your function. Try rewriting your file `functionsFile.php` like this:

```
<?php
    require_once ('databaseConnection.php');

    // No need to pass in connection information if this file is the one loading it and it's not scoped.
    function fillForm($table)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        $smt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $smt->execute();
        $rows = $smt->fetchAll();

        return $rows;
    }
```

Now, in your `order.php` file, you can load this file in and then use this function's returned data after it executes like so:

```
<?php
    require_once ('functionsFile.php');
?>

<form method="post" action=""><!-- You can leave the action blank if it is posting to the same file. -->
    <select name="order_status" id="order_status">
    <?php
        $rows = fillForm('order_status');

        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['order_status'] . '">' . $row['order_status'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <select name="customer" id="customer">
    <?php
        $rows = fillForm('customer');

        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['customer'] . '">' . $row['customer'] . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select>
    <!-- Next groups, etc. -->
</form>
```

This will allow you to reuse the `fillForm()` function as much as you need by only passing in the table name and will also give you more control over how you want your data to be displayed on a per table basis.

For your other questions,

1. You don't necessarily need to pass in field names if you are selecting everything. If you don't mind grabbing all the columns, this will allow you to access what you need outside of the `fillForm()` function. As for naming conventions, I wouldn't name the column identically to the table. Instead, I would give the table a broad, plural name, and I would name the column specifically to what that column is storing. E.g. Table -> Customers | Column1 -> Id | Column2 -> Name
2. I'm not exactly sure how to answer this one. Just make sure you understand everything you are writing before you actually try to use it. Do you mean the output of the function, or the output of html from php?

Answer (score 2):

There is two errors i can see in your code

Try This:

```
function fillForm($conn, $table)
 {
    foreach ($table as $menu)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM' .$menu;
        $smt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $smt->execute();
        $data = $smt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```